# Getting files and folders in the datalake while reading from datafactory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

While reading azure sql table data (which actually consists of path of the directories) from azure data factory by using the paths how to dynamically get the files from the datalake.

Can any one tell me what should I give in the dataset

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTO3v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to read data from azure sql, and then following it by an foreach activity. And then, pass @item(). to your dataset parameter k1.

[image]

[image]